# Counting the number of occurrences of a character in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

How can I count the number of times that a particular character occurs in a column in Oracle?  For example, if I have a table `FOO` that has data like `a,ABC,def` and `2,3,4,5`, I want to count the number of times that a comma appears in the data.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  str varchar2(30)
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES( 'a,ABC,def' );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES( '2,3,4,5' );
commit;
```

The output that I want is

```
str         cnt
a,ABC,def   2
2,3,4,5     3
```

Comment: using pl/sql i have got.

Comment: not getting using oracle sql..

Comment: Try the option from this link https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Answer (score 30):

One of the usual tricks for this is to use a combination of `length` and `replace`:

```
select (length(your_col) - length(replace(your_col, ','))) from your_table;
```

[`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) without a third argument will simply remove the character.

Answer (score 22):

Depending on your Oracle version (`regexp_count` was introduced in 11.1), I would tend to find it clearer to do something like

```
SELECT regexp_count( <<column_name>>, ',' )
  FROM <<table_name>>
```

which you can see with your table

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select str, regexp_count( str, ',' )
  2*   from foo
SQL> /

STR                            REGEXP_COUNT(STR,',')
------------------------------ ---------------------
a,ABC,def                                          2
2,3,4,5                                            3
```

Comment: @Sharath:I think this question should come with different question in stackoverflow...  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042568/difference-between-strong-and-weak-ref-cursor-in-oracle]

Comment: Only in Oracle Database 11g+

Comment: Hi, when I tried `select regexp_count('AB|C|D%E','|') from dual;` it returned 9. Why is it happening for pipe?

Comment: @Mistu4u, you need to escape the pipe, as that is a reserved character in regular expressions (same for periods and others): `select regexp_count('AB|C|D%E','\|') from dual;`